# CSS column align

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble aligning the multi-column footer. This is what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/98xyG/

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div id="aboutus"><h4>About Us</h4></div>
    <div id="contact"><h4>Contact Us</h4></div>
    <div id="location"><h4>Headquarters</h4></div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
    clear:both;
}
footer  #aboutus{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:73%;
    width:33%;
    height:1px;
}
footer #contact{
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-right: 30%;
    height:1px;
}
footer #location{
    margin-left: 73%;
    height:1px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the height to 1px?

Comment: When styling elements by ID, don't use any other selectors. It's pointless. I.e: `footer #contact {}` is the same as `#contact {}`, just slower.

Comment: @j08691 If you dont have the 1px then they will not be directly next to eachother.

Comment: @thykka I know, I just did that for myself, when I am looking at the css I can easily tell which section it is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
footer {overflow: hidden}
footer > div {float: left;}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98xyG/1/

Comment: I have a question. What exactly is this `footer > div` doing? I've never seen a > used in css. Great answer though.

Comment: It fires all `div`s which are **direct** children of `footer`.

Comment: This is a game changer for me! I never knew that existed. Thanks guys. @j08691